# How to view <remarks> documentation comments in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, documentation-generation

Microsoft's page on the subject (below) claims that they show in the object browser window, but I can't see them?

> The  tag is used to add information about a type,
>   supplementing the information specified with <summary>. This
>   information is displayed in the Object Browser Window.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zw4z1ys.aspx

Comment: This is still an issue.